# connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: database, postgresql, jcr

I am trying to take dump from my jackrabbit databases .

i got below mentioned error :-

```
pg_dump.bin: [archiver (db)] connection to database "jackrabbit" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
```

PostgreSQL is running on default port 5433 .

Comment: check this `netstat -apn` so find if port 5433 is listening on 5433 port

Comment: netstat -ant | grep LISTEN , as my service is down , i couldn't find 5433 in current service list

Comment: Thanks for the info , i will be removing them now@a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Did you read the error message and do what it suggested? `Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5433?`

Comment: can you be specific @ Craig Ringer

Comment: Restart your database & check if port is listening